# Google Spreadsheet Script for Deleting Rows with Given Value in Given Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am looking to delete rows that have a zero in column E in a particular row range. I have the following script, which will delete the rows with a zero in column E but this seems to apply to the whole spreadsheet.

```
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

   var rowsDeleted = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
   var row = values[i];
   if (row[4] == 0 || row[4] == '') {
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;
   }
  }
```

I am looking for help in applying this to a range, such as row 10 through row 20 rather than the entire spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry, the full script does have the function name at the top. I am not sure I understand you comment, I honestly found some of this script elsewhere and adapted it for my use so I may have some in there that doesn't need to be. Would what you are suggesting allow me to set the deletion to a certain range of rows?

Comment: A question about a problem should include the minimum necessary information to allow others to reproduce the problem. In the case of script, a function statement is required to be able to run the script, so please include it in script in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks that the OP code was taken from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15348040/1595451) by [Mike Grace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117068/mike-grace) to [Delete a row in Google Spreadsheets if value of cell in said row is 0 or blank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11058019/1595451)

The code doesn't check the entire spreadsheet, just the data range. Anyway to check only the rows from 10 to 20 replace

```
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
```

by

```
for (var i = 9; i <= 20 - 1; i++) {
```